# Axes Range change dynamically

Tags: range, plotly, axis, scatter3d

Does anybody know how can I change axis range in plotly's scatter3D via button click. I use relayout but it doesn't work

```
function updatet() {
   Plotly.relayout(‘myDiv’, ‘zaxis.range’, [[0, 100]]);
}
```

Nothing happens (my range is still [0,1800])

Answer (score 0):

For 3D plots `zaxis.range` needs to be inside [`scene`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-scene-zaxis-range) in order to work.

Note: Your ticks look like some copy&paste/autoformat problem.

```js
Plotly.d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/3d-scatter.csv', function(err, rows) {
  function unpack(rows, key) {
    return rows.map(function(row) {
      return row[key];
    });
  }
  var trace1 = {
    x: unpack(rows, 'x1'),
    y: unpack(rows, 'y1'),
    z: unpack(rows, 'z1'),
    mode: 'markers',
    marker: {
      size: 12,
      line: {
        color: 'rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.14)',
        width: 0.5
      },
      opacity: 0.8
    },
    type: 'scatter3d'
  };
  var trace2 = {
    x: unpack(rows, 'x2'),
    y: unpack(rows, 'y2'),
    z: unpack(rows, 'z2'),
    mode: 'markers',
    marker: {
      color: 'rgb(127, 127, 127)',
      size: 12,
      symbol: 'circle',
      line: {
        color: 'rgb(204, 204, 204)',
        width: 1
      },
      opacity: 0.9
    },
    type: 'scatter3d'
  };
  var data = [trace1, trace2];
  var layout = {
    margin: {
      l: 0,
      r: 0,
      b: 0,
      t: 0,
    }
  };
  Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
});

document.getElementById('updateButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  Plotly.relayout('myDiv', 'scene.zaxis.range', [0, 10 * Math.random()]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js">
</script>
<div id="myDiv" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>
<button id='updateButton'>Change axis
</button>
```